# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage render a title and position hamburger menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create something close to this (ignore the orange lines).  The red boxes illustrate the areas I am highlighting for this question.

I need the title MY DRIVES to appear and the hamburger menu to be on the right.

[image]

Here is what I have so far.  Notice there is no title and the hamburger menu is on the left.

[image]

Here is the code I have so far...

```
        var navPage = new NavigationPage();

        navPage.PushAsync(new MainPage());

        navPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#174873");
        navPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;
        navPage.Title = "MY DRIVES";

        App.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
        {
            Master = new MenuPage()
            {
                Title = "Master Page Title"
            },
            Detail = navPage
        };
```

How can I accomplish the UI in the first picture?